# asp.net ajax hovermenuextender on modalpopupextender z-index problem

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have an asp.net ajax hovermenuextender on a modalpopup panel to display a tip on hover.

the problem is the (tip) panel with the hovermenuextender appears below the modalpopupextender in IE8

this is a z-index issue, is there any place in the page where i can set the z-index for the hovermenu so that it appears over modalpopup, 
i learnt that this change could be made in the PopupBehavior.js file from here:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26107

but i am using the Ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll in the project and its not possible to modify the ajax javascript source files.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have running version AJAX 3.0 and adjusting the z-index did the trick. Thank you!
Make sure your PopupMenu container has higher z-index than the modal popup control. If you use Firefox with Firebug plugin you can find it easily when the page  gets rendered. Just right click on the modal popup background -> Inspect element with Firebug -> on the right side swap to the "Computed" tab and you will find the current z-index in the object properties.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS classes for your Modal Popup and the Model Background you can try adding an overriding z-index entry that is less than the default for the hover menu popup.  Something like:

```
.dialog {
  z-index: 99 !important;
}

.dialog-bkg {
  z-index: 90 !important;
}
```

Apply the "dialog" class to your modal popup panel, and supply the "dialog-bkg" class in the BackgroundCssClass property of the ModalPopupExtender.

I don't know if it will solve the issue with the hover menu -- but it may be worth a try.

BTW -- I just tested with version 4.1.404 of the Ajax Control Toolkit and I was able to use a hover menu on top of a modal popup without needing any changes...

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply but the version that's available for download online is this one: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475  ... and this looks like 4.0 version ...could you send me the link to download version 4.1, will be very helpful ...also .. is 4.1 a stable version or beta ?... thanks again

Comment: @user630536:  If you go to that page and download the AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET4.zip, the version on the assembly is 4.1.404.  Of course, that version only works with .NET 4.0 -- not sure what version you are using...

Comment: i use vs2008 (.net 3.5). So i guess this means with .net 3.5 there is no workaround but to create some custom hover menu's ?

Comment: Did you try overriding the z-indexes via CSS as mentioned above?

Comment: That's too bad...  You can always edit the toolkit like you mentioned and compile it from source.  It's not hard -- you just need to install the free MS Ajax minifier tool in your VS environment first.